# Flurry logAllPageViews deprecated

Tags: ios, flurry

I just updated to Flurry SDK 5.4. I get this warning on the compiler:

```
'logAllPageViews:' is deprecated
```

I looked at the flurry documentation and they have only updated it to 4.3 it looks like. If it is deprecated, what should I change it to?

```
[Flurry docs][1]
```

Thanks,

PS: I'm using XCode 6.1

Answer (score 4):

It is now called:

```
+ (void)logAllPageViewsForTarget:(id)target
```

where *target* can be a navigation or tab bar controller.